# Sobre a estrutura do verbo "doer"

Tags: verbos, sintaxe

Olá, gostaria de entender como é usado o verbo *doer*. Segundo os dicionários que eu consultei, doer é um verbo intransitivo. Mas é comum ver construções como:

> me dói a cabeça 
> dói minha cabeça

Acredito que, no segundo exemplo, *minha cabeça* atue como sujeito do verbo doer. O mesmo acredito que valha para o termo *a cabeça* no primeiro exemplo. Mas qual função tem o pronome *me* no primeiro exemplo? Não seria ele objeto do verbo? E se *minha cabeça* e *a cabeça* são sujeito, existe algum motivo de porque colocamos geralmente esses termos depois do verbo?

Comment: Acho idiomático dizer: Me dói a cabeça ou A cabeça me doi. E:  A minha cabeça dói quando eu {sei-lá-o-que].  *doer* é intransitivo. O uso de *me* acaba sendo pronominal. Em todo caso, em ambas frases,  o sujeito é cabeça. Pouco importa se estiver no comeco ou não.

Answer (score 5):

O verbo *“doer”* é intransitivo (ou transitivo indireto, tratarei desse
caso mais adiante).  Não há objeto direto.  Em ambos os casos,
*“cabeça”* forma o sujeito da oração.

O que ocorre é a topicalização do verbo, um tipo de transformação
sintática em que o verbo é movido para antes do sujeito.
Sintaticamente, a transformação que gera *“dói minha cabeça”* a partir
de “minha cabeça dói”, não é diferente da transformação que produz
*“cairam os livros”* ou *“sumiu o copo”* a partir de suas contrapartes
SVO.

Não pude encontrar artigos sobre a topicalização de verbos na língua
portuguesa, então, infelizmente, não posso citar fontes. Mas trata-se
de uma transformação simples.

Se você me permite opinar, creio que essa transformação parece ser
comum a verbos experienciais, em que o sujeito sofre as ações do verbo.
Não achei fontes que corroboram esta minha teoria.

Quanto a *“me dói a cabeça”*, o que ocorre é um fenômeno sintático
chamado *possessão externa*.

### Possessão externa

A frase “me dói a cabeça” usa um tipo de construção chamada “possessão
externa”, ou, mais especificamente, “possessão externa por pronome
clítico dativo”.  [Dafne Palu](https://libstore.ugent.be/fulltxt/RUG01/002/304/101/RUG01-002304101_2016_0001_AC.pdf) descreve esse tipo de construção na
língua portuguesa em seu artigo.  Citando a autora (traduzido por mim):

> Basicamente, possessão externa acontece quando o possessor e a
> posse “falham em formar um constituinte nominal único”.  Línguas
> europeias, incluindo Português e suas contrapartes românicas,
> geralmente expressam possessão ao codificar o possesor como um clítico
> dativo.

Noutras palavras, enquanto que na construção sintática chamada
“possessão interna”, o possessor e a posse formam um único sintagma
(isto é, uma única estrutura sintática), como em *“Eu penteei seus
cabelos”*, onde *“seus cabelos”* forma um sintagma nominal único, usado
como objeto da oração, com o possessor sendo o pronome possessivo
*“seus”* e a posse sendo o substantivo *“cabelos”*; na “possessão
externa”, o possessor e a posse encontram-se em sintagmas diferentes.
Exemplos de possessão externa são:

- *Penteei-lhe os cabelos.*
- *Me tomaram a bola.*
- *Toquei-lhe a mão.*
- *No outro dia, lavei-lhe o cabelo.*

Esse tipo de construção não é comúm só no Português, demais línguas
latinas e outras línguas europeias que formam o Sprachbund chamado
*“[Standard Average European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Average_European)”* (algo como *“Europeu Padrão Médio”*)
também tendem a ter tal construção.

Neste tipo de construção, o pronome oblíquo átono é usado com sentido
dativo (objeto indireto). Portanto, *“Me dói a cabeça”* equivale,
sintaticamente, a *“A mim dói a cabeça”*, usando a contraparte tônica do
pronome oblíquo.  Apesar da equivalência sintática, a segunda forma não
é comum. Note que *me*, neste caso, não é objeto direto do verbo *doer*.

### Verbo transitivo indireto

Há porém uma outra forma para o verbo “doer”, na qual ele é transitivo
indireto, e suporta um objeto indireto.  Novamente, não há objeto direto
para este verbo.

O dicionário [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/doer) define *“doer”*, no sentido 3°, como “provocar
dor física ou moral (em)”.  Neste caso o verbo é transitivo indireto e o
objeto indireto é a quem (ou o quê) dói, enquanto que o sujeito é a
causa da dor.

Nesta interpretação, a sua frase pode ser entendida como “a cabeça
provoca dor em mim”. Esta interpretação é ligeiramente diferente de
“a cabeça dói”.  Porém, imagino que esta interpretação não seja aquela a
qual você se refere na pergunta.

Comment: Bons olhos te leiam! Tens a certeza do "Feriram-no no pescoço"? Eu esperaria *feriram-lhe o pescoço*. Eu conheço isto como *dativo de posse*; nunca ouvi falar de *acusativo de posse*. Além disso, se tirares "no pescoço" ficas com uma frase bem formada, "feriram-no", em que *(n)o* é simplesmente o complemento direto.

Comment: Olá, Jacinto. Quanto tempo! De fato, o *Feriram-no no pescoço* é um exemplo de possessão externa por acusativo. Eu retirei o exemplo do artigo da Dafne Palú sem prestar muita atenção ao paragrafo que o precede e o explica. Corrigido.

Comment: Parece-me que verbos não podem ser tópicos. A Gramática do Português da Gulbenkian (vol. I, p. 407) discute os exemplos *chegou a Rita; não se acabou o chá; telefonaram uns alunos teus*, e diz que eles não têm uma estrutura tópico-comentário; diz que o sujeito em posição pós-verbal não é tópico, mas não diz que o verbo o seja.